# C# not receiving Post

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a webapi app in C#. I'm using postman to send post requests to the api, but when Calling the function, the received parameter is null.

It seems that C# is not seeing any content of the post message.

This is my WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Lab1_v5
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Lab1_API.Models;
namespace Lab1_API.Controllers
{
    public class OperacionController : ApiController
    {
        public Operacion ProcesarResultado(Operacion op)
        {
            return Models.Operacion.Procesar(op);
        }


    }
}
```

This is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Lab1_API.Models
{
    public class Operacion
    {

        private double value1, value2, resultado;
        private int tipoOperacion;

        public double Value1 { get => value1; set => value1 = value; }
        public double Value2 { get => value2; set => value2 = value; }
        public double Resultado { get => resultado; set => resultado = value; }
        public int TipoOperacion { get => tipoOperacion; set => tipoOperacion = value; }

        public Operacion(double pvalue1, double pvalue2, double presultado, int ptipoOperacion)
        {
            this.Value1 = pvalue1;
            this.Value2 = pvalue2;
            this.Resultado = presultado;
            this.TipoOperacion = ptipoOperacion;
        }

        public Operacion(double pvalue1, double pvalue2, int ptipoOperacion)
        {
            this.Value1 = pvalue1;
            this.Value2 = pvalue2;
            this.Resultado = 0;
            this.TipoOperacion = ptipoOperacion;
        }

        public static Operacion Procesar(Operacion op)
        {
            double result = 0;
            switch (op.tipoOperacion)
            {
                case 1: 
                    result = op.Value1 + op.Value2;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    result = op.Value1 - op.Value2;
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    result = op.Value1 * op.Value2;
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    result = op.Value1 + op.Value2;
                    break;
            }
            op.resultado = result;
            return op;
        }
    }


}
```

I'm sending this as Json with the header `"application/json"`:

```
{
    "Value1":1.0,
    "Value2":1.0,
    "Resultado":0.0,
    "TipoOperacion":1
}
```

I've tryied pretty much everything and I can't seem to understand why I'm getting a null in the Controller.

EDIT -

The URL I'm using to reach the webapi is: http://localhost:55236/api/Operacion/ProcesarResultado.

Comment: Could you add the example of URL of your request?

Comment: http://localhost:55236/api/Operacion/ProcesarResultado/

Comment: Add this to your question and add specify the verb which you use (e.g. `POST`, `GET`). It's hard to understand the reason of the problem without this information.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, still getting null

Comment: @GinoMarin Have you tried providing a parameterless constructor to `Operacion`?

Comment: ckuri that actually worked! Could you explain to me what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you answer on an actual answer and not a comment so I can mark that as solution?

Comment: @GinoMarin Done as you proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from possibly not marking your method as accepting POST requests, your model is missing a parameterless constructor. It should be

```
public class Operacion
{

    private double value1, value2, resultado;
    private int tipoOperacion;

    public double Value1 { get => value1; set => value1 = value; }
    public double Value2 { get => value2; set => value2 = value; }
    public double Resultado { get => resultado; set => resultado = value; }
    public int TipoOperacion { get => tipoOperacion; set => tipoOperacion = value; }

    public Operacion()
    {
    }

    // other constructors and methods
}
```

The parameterless constructor is required for the framework to instantiate your class, as it can't use your constructors with parameters, because it doesn't know how to fill them.

If you have a model without explicitely declaring any constructors, a default parameterless constructor is automatically generated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the HttpPost attribute or start the method name with Post.

```
[HttpPost]
public Operacion ProcesarResultado(Operacion op)
{
    return Models.Operacion.Procesar(op);
}
```

or

```
public Operacion PostProcesarResultado(Operacion op)
{
    return Models.Operacion.Procesar(op);
}
```

Comment: @GinoMarin Try adding an empty constructor to your Operacion class, we had some problems with that in a WebAPI once.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the header of the request. Try to add

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: The header is specified in Postman just like that, still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the method on the controller is for a POST request.  Use the `HttpPost` attribute.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Operacion ProcesarResultado(Operacion op)
    {
        return Models.Operacion.Procesar(op);
    }
```

Comment: I added that and nothing. I still get Null as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mark your parameter with `FromBodyAttribute` like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public Operacion ProcesarResultado([FromBody] Operacion op)
{
    return Models.Operacion.Procesar(op);
}
```

This should suggest framework to deserialize request body. Without it it may be expecting form data.

Comment: Complex types like classes are always transferred in the body by default, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I added it and nothing changed. It seems that the parameter "op" is absolutely null. It's not like it has a different deserialization or it is receiving something else, it just comes empty

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with Your constructor. 
Quick fix:
Just add parameterless constructor:

```
public Operacion()
            {
            }
```

And don't forget to name Your action properly (start action name with: Post) or add [HttpPost] attribute before action definition (if You leave it like this it can add some more problems).